# How to view an image from blob column in Oracle with JasperReports?

Tags: java, oracle, jasper-reports

I tried defining an image element in the report layout and setting type to java.io.Inputstream but that doesn't work, also I tried setting to java.awt.Image and neither works, the exception that I'm getting is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.BLOB cannot be cast to java.awt.Image
```

or

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.BLOB cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream
```

Also I tried to google but the results are that what I'm doing right now.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing how you're calling the blob to embed the image within your report code...

1. Use [`blob.getBinaryStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/BLOB.html#getBinaryStream__).
2. Convert the stream using [`javax.imageio.ImageIO.read( InputStream )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29).

For example:

```
javax.imageio.ImageIO.read( blob.getBinaryStream() )
```

This will return an instance of [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), which subclasses `java.awt.Image`, and should be a suitable object to embed in the report.

The `blob` variable shown in the example will have to use the appropriate variable from the report (that represents the data from the desired column).

See also:

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2081381

Comment: Thanks, this just works for me.
Initially I was passing the blob to the report parameter without any type of cast or streaming conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) yourBlobData);
myImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "image/png");
```

in jsf page;

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{controller.myImage}" style="width:200px;width:500px" />
```