# Display BLOB image from Oracle in Jasper Report

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports

I am trying to show image from BLOB data in Jasper Reports.

Database : `Oracle 12c`

Jasper : `Jasper iReport 4.7.1`

I follow these steps :

1. Change the field class of the column fetched from Database .

   `Field Class = java.io.InputStream`
2. Add a image in the report and change the expression class to : `java.awt.Image`

Still doesn't work.

It says that :

`Error displaying report page. See the console for details.`

Then when I check `iReport console` it doesn't show anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export an image that is a blob in database from a jasper reports to excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894102/how-to-export-an-image-that-is-a-blob-in-database-from-a-jasper-reports-to-excel), I hope it helps you if not let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view an image from blob column in Oracle with JasperReports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272283/how-to-view-an-image-from-blob-column-in-oracle-with-jasperreports)